# How to render text on right side of screen in Java

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm currently making a Minecraft mod, and I need to render text so that it aligns with the right side of the screen. I know the way to do this in CSS is by setting the `right` property to 0, or however many pixels you need the text off the right side of the screen.

However, I can't seem to find anything relating to this in Java. Minecraft comes with some default functions you can use to render text. I am using `mc.fontRendererObj.drawString(<text>, <x>, <y>, <color>)` to draw text. You can also use the variable `GlStateManager` to modify the text using it's variables and functions.

I'm fairly certain that with these I can achieve what I'm trying to do, but I can't find a way to do it. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Minecraft mods, but I can suggest a way to right align your text, if you are interested.

Comment: I am interested, it doesn't necessarily have to use the functions I mentioned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `drawString` method, you need to calculate <x> and <y> such that the end of the text aligns with the right side of the area in which you are drawing the text. So you need to obtain the width of that area as well as the width of the text you are writing. Then you can calculate <x>. Of-course the <y> does not affect right-alignment. In pure java there are methods for obtaining the width and for the length of the text, both in pixels.

Comment: By the by, the `FontRenderer` class has a method for determining a string's width.